# Why python can't show the exact value of sin function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from math import sin, pi
print(sin(2*pi))
```

This code includes the value of sin(2pi) which equals to 0, but why python show this -2.4492935982947064e-16? and how to fix it?
Is it just the problem of my computer?

Comment: FYI: `2*pi` ≠ 2π.  See, for example, ["What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Furthermore, `pi` ≠ π.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe  there are no solution to calculate the exact value(0) of sin(2pi)  because of the floating-point problem.

Answer (score 1):

`pi` is not equal with `π`. you can use `sympy` instead.

```py
from sympy import sin, pi
print(sin(pi))  # 0
```